# Use Moscow Metro in a book

Tags: copyright, trademark

I'm publishing a short book about a trip to Moscow that I made. Is it OK for me to mention the Moscow Metro and specific stations?

Also I've described walking through it in the following way. Might this be considered defamatory?

> We must go with the flow into the belly of the beast; down a white
>   relatively featureless tunnel like workers marching in an urban
>   dystopia. We see our platform and squash into the train.

---

> We take a spectacularly noisy Metro ride

---

> approaches a man in a booth to ask for help but the man turns
>   away. I look at the man and he continues to look away but now looks a
>   bit awkward about doing it but he still does it.

[http://www.amazon.com/Marriage-Moscow-Ian-Warburton-ebook/dp/B011J47AOE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011J47AOE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something to be "defamatory," it has to be 1) certifiably "untrue" and 2) "highly offensive" to a reasonable person.

What you said is more of an opinion than a factual statement, you are entitled to your opinion and said nothing that was certifiably untrue. Moreover, what you said would not be "highly offensive" to a reasonable person.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

No.

Comment: Why not for the second question? I'm implying that its a bit grim.

Comment: Saying something is bad is not illegal.

Comment: That's good. :) So under what kind of circumstances would it be defamatory? When its factually false?

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem in using public places in your books, including the Moscow Metro. In fact the Moscow Metro is already the setting of the [Metro-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_of_Metro_2033) of novels by russian author Dmitry Glukhovsky. No problem here.

Answer (score 1):

The Moscow Metro is public transport so fair game to use in a story.

For any unfounded negative remarks, in case you are worried about consequences your can use a [disclaimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_persons_fictitious_disclaimer) thought that generally only is done for real live persons (that may take actions otherwise).